# Evaluation of given limit where $ n \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the given limit:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg[ \bigg(\frac{n}{n} \bigg)^n +\bigg(\frac{n-1}{n} \bigg)^n + \bigg(\frac{n-2}{n} \bigg)^n+....+\bigg(\frac{1}{n} \bigg)^n \bigg]$$

I was trying to calculate each limit separately. First bracket equals $1$, second bracket equals $1/e$ , third bracket equals $1/e^2$ and so on. But how to add up after that? Could someone help me with this?

Comment: false. the third bracket is 1/e^2

Comment: @SakethMalyala Yes. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: One can take limits term by term limits via monotone convergence theorem to get the answer as $e/(e-1)$.